# Is there a difference between "bauen" and "erbauen"?

Tags: word-usage, meaning

What is the difference between *bauen* and *erbauen*?

I mean, semantically. Or can they be used interchangeably?

Comment: "Peter baut eine Kirche" but not "Peter erbaut eine Kirche". "Die Kirche wurde erbaut[=errichtet]" and "Die Kirche wurde gebaut." In all other cases you only use "bauen".

Comment: @Em1 So _Die Kirche wurde erbaut_ means _The church was built_, and _Die Kirche wurde gebaut_ means _The church was built_. I may be slow-witted (I don't deny it), but I honestly don't get where the difference lies.

Comment: Hahaha... Honestly, there's no significant difference between "Die Kirche wurde erbaut" and "Die Kirche wurde gebaut". Imho, the only difference is that *erbauen* is more about the process while *bauen* is more about the result.

Comment: And don't forget "(wieder) aufbauen" ;)

Comment: Here's a quite good answer in German. http://de.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20100129174530AADwtcy

Comment: Spontan würde ich raten, dass `erbaut` nur für Immobilien benutzt wird, bin mir dessen aber nicht sicher. Lokomotiven, Joints und Software werden gebaut, aber nicht erbaut. Außerdem gibt es noch das Adjektiv(?): `Ich bin erbaut von Virginis Lächeln.` welches ich auch mit `wohlgestimmt, hochgestimmt, aufgemuntert` übersetzen würde.

Comment: A hint might be that `erbauen` is a somewhat old fashioned word for `erfreuen` often used in a religious context as in `Eine sehr erbauliche Predigt.` (See `Erbauungsschriften`). So I think `erbauen` has connotations of something grand, important, maybe even glorifying.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. *Erbauen* means rather *to erect* and *bauen,  to build* and I can't think of better examples as those given by @Em1 in the comments.

> Rom wurde auch nicht an einem Tag erbaut

Often the prefix *er* means the [prefix "re"](http://forum.pons.eu/de/forum-deutsch-englisch/deutsche-grammatik/prefix-er-t7051.html)  in English; however I think that one has to learn each verb separetly (I mean, the verb alone and with prefix), because the meanings of the verbs `er+verb` are not always guessable. The link above exhibits the pairs

> 1. *trinken* and *ertrinken*, which mean *to drink* and *to drown=drink repetitively to death*
> 2. *zählen* and *erzählen*, *to count* and *to re-count*
> 3. *kennen* and *erkennen*, *to know* and *recognize*.

Comment: But _Rom wurde auch nicht an einem Tag erbaut_ means _Rome was not built in a day_. But you said that _erbauen_ does not mean _to build_.

Comment: Well, I guess that for that particular example "build" means the same as "edify". I would say the word erbauen is used for the building big, important things.

Comment: Ouuuu.... Well. First I would be very careful about saying that *er* is often *re*. It might be true in some cases but *erbauen* is one example where it's not true. Otherwise it means that Rome had been rebuild ;) Consider *Er-* words independently; as new words. Different words. Anyway. About *edify*. I had to look up this word and from OALD, you're wrong. Looking at merriam-webster, you're archaic ;) *Erbauen* means *to edify* and *to uplift* and *to establish* but this is a **different context** and has nothing to do with *to build*. Again, the *build*-meaning in *to edify* is archaic.

Comment: Instead of *to edify* go with *[to erect](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/erect_2)*: to build something - The church was erected in 1582.